# Why does the T7 RNA Polymerase require a reducing environment ie. DTT

Tags: transcription, t7-promoter

Every bloody protocol suggests adding in DTT when doing *in vitro* RNA transcription. Why? The rationale seems to be that the cytoplasm traditionally has a reducing environment but as the only protein we care about is the T7 polymerase, why is this necessary.

Comment: You're right. I just looked up a couple of protocols (an example from [Promega](http://www.promega.com/~/media/Files/Resources/Protocols/Product%20Information%20Sheets/N/T7%20RNA%20Polymerase%20Protocol.ashx) ) and it has a final concentration of 10 mM DTT. They don't explain why, however it must be important for it to be included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick search on T7 cysteines gave some clues:

> Bacteriophage T7-induced DNA polymerase is composed of a 1: 1
>   complex of phage-induced gene 5 protein  and Escherichia coli
>   thioredoxin. Preparation of active  subunits in the absence of 
>   sulfhydryl  reagents  indicates  the reduced form of thioredoxin  is 
>   sufficient for formation of  the  active holoenzyme. The oxidized
>   form of  thioredoxin, thioredoxin modified  at  one  active  site 
>   sulfhydryl by iodoacetate or methyl iodide, or thioredoxin modified
>   at both  active  site  sulfhydryls  by N-ethylmaleimide,  are  all 
>   inactive,  being  defective  in  complex formation with  gene 5
>   protein.

[Adler and Modrich, J Biol Chem 258:6956 (1983)](http://www.jbc.org/content/258/11/6956.full.pdf)

There's a more recent paper ([Aguirre et al, Inorganic Chemistry 48:4425 (2009)](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic900164j)) that mentions the "*the enzyme critical sulfhydryl cysteine groups*", but unfortunately I only have access to the abstract.

**Update**: It seems to be an old finding, rather than a rationale concerning the cytoplasmic redox state. According to [Chamberlin and Ring, JBC 248:2235 (1973)](http://www.jbc.org/content/248/6/2235.full.pdf+html),

> General Requirements-The general requirements for T7 RNA 
>   synthesis directed by T7 DNA polymerase are shown in Table 
>   I. As expected for a template directed polymerase, RNA 
>   synthesis shows an absolute requirement for DNA, the 4 
>   ribonucleoside triphosphates and Mg++.

(no surprises there ;)

> The activity of the 
>   enzyme is reduced significantly if a sulfhydryl reducing 
>   agent such as b-mercapto-ethanol is omitted from  the 
>   reaction. The addition of 10^-5 M p-hydroxymercuribenzoate to
>   the assay system in the absence of b-mercaptoethanol 
>   abolished all activity, indicating that the enzyme contains a 
>   sulfhydryl group necessary for activity.

However, if you see the table I, the remaining activity after removing bme is still 74%

There seems to be 7 exposed cysteines ([Mukherjee et al, Cell 110:81 (2002)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867402008152)), but I could not find any paper discussing their roles.

Comment: Here's a copy of the paper. Enjoy.
http://cl.ly/101U380b3r261i0w0v1d

Comment: How strange. I'm looking at the crystal structure (1QLN) and there aren't a lot of cysteines near the active site. Will have to take a look at those papers.

Comment: @jp89 Thanks for the copy of the paper. I'm not sure though if this is allowed here, since it is breaking copyrights. Anyhow, for now I believe it is still fair use. Regarding to the question, I'd follow citations 59-62 from there (last paragraph on page 2/first on page 3). Cheers.

Comment: Bacteriophage polymerase is active within the cell, which has a reducing environment.  Most protocols of intracell proteins include DTT or glutathione for this reason.   Disulfides are mostly for secreted proteins.

Comment: @Aleadam Yeah, that is the sad case. I honestly don't understand the concept of copyrighting human knowledge.

Comment: @jp89 it is slowly improving, with the PLoS effort, and NIH manuscript requirements, but there is still a long way to go

Answer (score 1):

I always assumed it was because DTT is useful in inactivating ribonucleases (by reducing their disulfides) which are notoriously stable and pervasive. It would be pretty unfortunate to get your RNA synthesized only to have it immediately be destroyed by a contaminating RNase.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This may be correct, but answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if they are based on research rather than speculation. Consequently you should include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 