# Do birds have quadriceps and thighs fused into their hips?

Tags: zoology, anatomy

I'm looking at 3D modeling a large bird like an emu or ostrich, but I don't know how the muscles surrounding the femur connect to the hips/back. It seems weird that the entire thigh and quadriceps would be fused into the hip because that would greatly reduce the range of motion of the femur which affects how I animate it, but I can't find any reference that shows it either way.

Comment: Is ["Ontogenetic scaling patterns and functional anatomy of the pelvic limb musculature in emus (Dromaius novaehollandiae)"](https://peerj.com/articles/716/) not enough?

Comment: No it's not....

Comment: Have you tried googling avian muscle anatomy.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably WAAAAY to late to be of any use to you but hey...
So the simple answer is:
Kinda.
You were actually correct to intuit that the femora of birds have a limited range of motion, with most of the limb motion being provided from the "knee"-down.
So you shouldn't animate bird legs the same way that you would the legs of other non-bird animals.
That's not to say that the femur doesn't move - it does but not my much (it typically doesn't extend posteriorly beyond the vertical). Much of the thicc thigh musculature is there for support.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best) — that allows non-experts to confirm your assertions and learn more. Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609). ——— Please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 