# Myelination and time constant

Tags: action-potential, neuron

In textbooks, it says that myelination doesn't really affect the time constant as tau=RC where R is the membrane resistance and C is the membrane capacitance. Myelin increases membrane resistance while decreasing membrane capacitance so there isn't really an overall effect on the time constant. However, during active regeneration of the action potential, the current only goes the path with least resistance i.e. the nodes of Ranvier, so wouldn't the R be the resistance of the node of Ranvier instead of the resistance of the entire membrane as stated in the textbooks? If this argument is correct then wouldn't myelination increases decreases time constant? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the saltatory propagation of the action potential the constant of interest is not the membrane tau constant, but the [spatial lambda constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_theory). The decrease in membrane resistance due to mielination increases lambda, allowing the current to travel farther to the next Ranvier node.

In the Ranvier node there's a high concentration of ion channels that generates the current necessary to depolarize the next node.

Answer (score 0):

No. When a signal is sent through a myelinated axon, the Nodes of Ranvier act as repeaters in electronics. The signal/action potential will disperse down the axon, the Node of Ranvier will pick up the signal, amplify it, and send it to the subsequent Node of Ranvier. I think you're thinking of the Nodes of Ranvier as cracks in the myelin/axon rather than as mini re-amplification sites.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This looks like it might be a good answer, but answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best, but textbooks can be OK). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59695/how-do-trees-communicate-in-the-wood-wide-web?rq=1). ——— You may also want to take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 