# When does the vertebral column finish chondrifying and begin to ossify?

Tags: embryology, vertebra

I have read many articles on vertebral column development in embryos on the internet. 
Different articles give different time periods for the end of chondrification of the vertebral column and the beginning of ossification.

Some [websites](https://discovery.lifemapsc.com/library/review-of-medical-embryology/chapter-66-development-of-the-axial-skeleton) and books(like The Developing Human: Clinically Orientd Embryology 10th edition) say that 'the 2 centers in each centrum fuse at the end of the embryonic period to form a cartilaginous centrum', which is rather confusing since they also say that ossification begins in the 7th week. How can ossification in the centrum begin when the chondrification centers in the centrum have not even fused yet? Why does it takes so long(2 weeks) for the chondrification centers to fuse?

When is the chondrification of the vertebral column complete and when does ossification start?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, including references to your conflicting sources will improve your chances of getting a useful answer. In addition, please specify the organism for which you want an answer. ——— This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59695/how-do-trees-communicate-in-the-wood-wide-web?rq=1). Thanks! 

Comment: I've made some edits that I hope clarify your question, but I think it would be helpful if you could elaborate on why you think the quote (BTW: you [must add a reference](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for that quote) conflicts with "ossification begins in the 7th week".