# Is it possible to cultivate cheek epithelial cells in a non-CO2 incubator?

Tags: cell-culture, mammalian-cell-culture

CO2 is important for maintaining constant pH in cell culture. Unfortunately, I do not have access to such incubator and buying a new one is expensive. I found a cheap incubator online, but it doesn't support CO2. I'd like to ask if I can cultivate cheek epithelial cells in such incubator and if it won't negatively affect my cell culture. Another option is building a small CO2 generator inside the incubator. I made some calculations - I know how much CO2 I need to generate, how many grams and mL of solutions I need, moreover the build-up pressure is so small, it should not negatively affect the incubator.

Comment: Are you familiar with CO2-independent growth media? (I don't know anything about culture of that cell population specifically, though)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not familiar with CO2-independent growth media, but I will take a look. I planned to buy a cheap DMEM from eBay. I hope, there are some inexpensive media you mentioned, or at least a method to convert DMEM to such medium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[L-15 media](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/life-science/cell-culture/learning-center/media-formulations/l-15.html) does not require a CO<sub>2</sub> atmosphere and [according to Sigma-Aldrich](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/l5520) this media is suitable for primary explants of adult human tissues.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and [edit] your post accordingly. ———  Answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include some details and supporting references (primary literature is best, but at a minimum a link to a description of this media). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59695/how-do-trees-communicate-in-the-wood-wide-web?rq=1). Thank you! 