# What are the short/long term effects of chloroquine on fundamental cell processes?

Tags: cell-biology, virology, cell-membrane, coronavirus

Does chloroquine, which affects the endosomal membrane traffic pathway (by affecting the acid environment used for fundamental endosomal reactions), have short/long-term effects on cell growth/proliferation/signaling?

Answer (score 1):

This [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6103682/) provides many experiments about changes to the endosomal system and autophagy and should be a good starting point.
Most of the treatments are done in the 5h to 24h range typical for cell culture studies. In theis relatively short time frame Chloroquine is well tolerated by cells. However, long term treatment will very likely be different.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This looks like it could be the start of a good answer, but you haven't actually answered the question. Answers should be self-sufficient (and not require further reading) and have references supplied to support statements made in the answer. This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59695/how-do-trees-communicate-in-the-wood-wide-web?rq=1). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for details and additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 