# Why do meristematic cells have prominent nuclei and dense cytoplasm?

Tags: cell-biology, plant-anatomy, tissue

I've been reading about meristematic cells having prominent nuclei and dense cytoplasm. However, I could not understand why it is that way. Could somebody please explain?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  "I've been reading..."  would it be possible to elaborate a bit?  Context as to what you have been reading would help us understand the question.  Direct quotes is best with links for reference if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: It's from a textbook from school. The book points out the basic characteristics of meristematic cells. "As the cells of this tissue are very active, they have dense cytoplasm, thin cellulose walls and prominent nuclei." I understand that the cells are active but I do not understand as to why that would lead to having prominent nuclei and dense cytoplasm. @rotaredom

Answer (score -1):

Because meristamatic cells are the ones who are undergoing mitosis to increase the height of the plant, and diameter of the plant . They undergo continuous division. So y hey don't mature. They only form the primary cell wall. [image]
I wrote another a answer.  Perhaps this will answer the question [image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This looks like it could become a good answer, but to do so you need to connect "continuous division" and lack of maturation with the described "prominent nuclei and dense cytoplasm". I would expect it to also mention vacuoles. In addition, answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if they include supporting references (primary literature is best, but a textbook would work for this). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ...

Comment: ... The is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59695/how-do-trees-communicate-in-the-wood-wide-web?rq=1). ——— You may also want to take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 