# What happens if ace2 from lungs is removed? Will there be any major impact on our body?

Tags: respiration, health, lungs

when ace2 receptors  are not present in the lungs will we experience any disturbance or suffer from any other problems

Comment: Yes, the  renin–angiotensin system is very important. Search about ACE2 knockout mice https://physoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1113/expphysiol.2007.040014

Answer (score 0):

According to my cursory and unprofessional assessment, the most prominent issue would be hypertension, flanked by excessive retention of water, sodium ions, and chloride ions, due to the boatloads of angiotensin II just sitting around. Potassium ions would be excreted gratuitously, however. The lack of the ACE2 receptors has been (ostensibly) linked to Hartnup disease as well, so make of that what you will.

Once again, I'm not a medical professional, so take my word with a bucketful of salt.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This looks like a could become a good answer if you provided more detail and included supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. A good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59695/how-do-trees-communicate-in-the-wood-wide-web?rq=1). ——— Please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then [edit] your answer accordingly. Thank you! 

Comment: @tyersome My apologies, I’m new and I come from quora, so my standards are a tad low.