# What kind of snakes are in this photo?

Tags: species-identification, snake

What is the name of these snakes? I saw them in the street and I don't know if they are dangerous for people? Photo is taken near to Tbilisi, Georgia.

[image: snakes on dirt]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions should include: 1) the species-identification tag; 2) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; 3) habitat information; and 4) an estimate of the size of the organism. Please [edit] your post to include this information as it can be essential for a proper identification. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: @tyersome why do you keep downvoting me? What kind of information are you looking for? The OP only provided a photo and a location. That means identification must rely on appearance and location and can be easily verified by examining other photos of the putative species.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Anguis colchica]Based on the species description in Speybroeck et al. 2016 and pattern of stripes (one central stripe with stripes on each side), and the lack of a distinct neck, the specimen in the top left appears to be an Eastern slow worm (*Anguis colchica*). That species is known to occur in Tbilisi.

Based on the species description in Speybroeck et al. 2016 a smooth snake (*Coronella austriaca*), also known from Tbilisi. The reddish color, two rows of dark spots, and the markings on the head are typical of this species. Also it can be seen that the anal scales are divided, which is a characteristic of this species. [image: Coronella austriaca]

Cited
Speybroeck et al. 2016. Field Guide to the Amphibians and Reptiles of Britain and Europe. Bloomsbury Natural History (publ).

Comment: I haven't downvoted this answer! I may have downvoted other posts by you, but I almost always post a comment before I downvote. ——— This answer looks OK to me, but please make sure that you credit image sources. Another improvement would be to include complete reference information — an easy way to get that information is to search for the paper on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/) and click on the ‟ symbol to get reference information. This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609).

Comment: Also note that it costs reputation to downvote answers, so if you are getting a lot of downvotes on answers that suggests that you might also want to revisit some of your other posts and see if they also can be improved. The [tour] and [help] pages such as [Answer] should provide guidance and you can also consult on [meta]. ——— Note that moderators put up the banners; therefore at least one has felt your post lacked sufficient references, but I think that was before your recent edits. Hope this helps!

Comment: Does Stack Biology fancy itself a kind of scientific journal, where people publish the results of research and provide references to back up claims? Or is it simply a public forum where knowledgeable people can share their knowledge with less experienced people in an open informal exchange? I thought it was the latter but it seems to have become the former.