# Is there any ethnicity difference in average pupil size?

Tags: human-anatomy, anatomy

I have seen some articles claim African Americans have smaller average pupils than whites while Asians have larger pupils. Is it true?

link:
[Y. Li, D. Huang; Pupil Size and Iris Thickness Difference Between Asians and Caucasians Measured by Optical Coherence Tomography. Invest. Ophthalmol. Vis. Sci. 2009;50(13):5785.](https://iovs.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2368143#:%7E:text=The%20average%20pupil%20size%20was,respectively%20(p%20%3C%200.00001).&text=Caucasian%201.83%20%2B%2F%2D%200.22%20mm2%2C%20p%3D0.135)

Comment: if you've "seen some articles", it would be good to cite them/give links in your question ...

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, we expect you to demonstrate that you have done research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). ——— In this case, I suggest finding and providing references to any primary research that supports these claims. Thanks! 

Comment: Please also include the complete reference information since links can (and do) break. One easy way to get that information is to search for the paper on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/) and click on the ‟ symbol to get reference information. This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609).

Comment: Note nowhere does it say they controlled for height, which is not equally distributed. A control for different heights would be important. A comparison based on latitude for a developmental effect would also be useful.