# metaphors for explaining the role of DNA in the cell

Tags: genetics, cell-biology, dna, genomics

Various metaphors are used to explain the central role of DNA in a cell to laypersons. These include blueprint, recipe, catalogue, instruction manual etc. I even heard someone describing DNA as a 'boss' that yells orders.

Here are some interesting ones:

1. An ancestral archive
2. An archeological site
3. A prison (retroviruses and transposons)
4. A computer
5. A deck of cards
6. A clock

What are some useful metaphors that help to explain DNA function?

Comment: You just answered your question 11 times, if I count correctly. What is it you wish to know? Other metaphors? If yes, I think such a discussion-type question should be posted in chat, not on the main site.

Comment: It is clearly off-topic, but this doesn't appear to be homework @John. & homework questions aren't off-topic. Only if they do not conform to the other rules.

Comment: I answered. What about you? Good metaphors are essential to conveying complex or domain information and a pillar of education. Have a try!

Answer (score 1):

It is a program executed by transcriptase (processor) inside a cell core (computer).

Comment: Since this is an off-topic question (it is opinion rather than fact based), it is better left unanswered. For future posts please note that answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609). ——— Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 

Comment: Thats my intuition also -  that 'computation' is occurring in the transcriptome rather than the genome