# Why we need a plasmid for r-DNA technology

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, biotechnology, plasmids

Recently I was studying Biotechnology. When I went through the texts, I had a doubt: both plasmids and gene of interest are made of DNA stretches and bacteria directly absorb plasmids in a test tube (where reactions take place). Why is the gene of interest not directly put in the test tube instead of recombinant DNA Technology (using Edited plasmids), so that it gets absorbed by bacteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plasmid has a site necessary for replication of genetic material know as the origin of replication (ori) since gene of interest (GOI) is just a segment of DNA it only posseses the sequence of interest and lacks an ori site, due to this it will not be able to replicate by itself. Replication of GOI is important for product formation in r-DNA technology (mostly protien) as when the host cells divides the GOI is duplicated and is transferred to both daughter cells. This way the number of recombinant cells will increase hence producing more of the final product.

Comment: Please add some references to your answer and maybe add some descriptions to the technical terms you have used.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This looks like the start of a good answer (note that plasmids also add stability and selectability), but answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609). ——— Thank you for taking the [tour], but please also consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 