# Alternative dyes for Gram staining

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, lab-techniques, lab-reagents, staining

In the Gram stain, is there any replacement for primary stain, secondary stain, decolourizer and mordant? What results will the replacements produce?

I found that crystal violet can be replaced with methylene blue but in that case, what will the secondary stain, mordant etc. be? Please also explain what result we might get.

Answer (score 9):

As you may have realized, crystal violet can be replaced by a lot of dyes since the ethanol will wash out the dye from the gram negative cells. Methylene blue is a nice choice - malachite green may also work.

A weak concentration of hydrochloric acid (3%) is also a possible replacement for the ethanol. A 3% HCl solution is used in the acid-fast stain but it may be too strong for non-acid fast cells. It would be worth testing it out and trying it to see if it could replace the ethanol step.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This looks like it might be a good answer, but answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion to a non-expert — it also helps users by providing resources for further learning. ——— [A good example of how to format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609). ——— You may also want to take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you!