# An apple sunk in water, looks fine. What could it mean?

Tags: fruit

I washed a dozen of apple just now and one of them sunk in water. Also surprisingly I was not able to find an answer via googling, all top results were about why they float. [image]

The smallest one. I don't know the variety name, but AFAIK it is an apple, tastes like an apple. Could a fact that it sunk mean some internal spoilage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Section of an apple]

Image Source: [Infovisual: Apple](https://infovisual.info/en/biology-vegetal/apple)

I think that the density of the endocarp is more than the mesocarp, and in that small apple, more amount of endocarp is present than mesocarp, making its average density more than water, thus, making it sink. Vice versa for the bigger apples.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This looks like it might be a good answer, but answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion, which is inappropriate for this site. A good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609).  Please also provide a reference for the image you used. ——— You may also want to take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site.

Comment: @tyersome Thank you. I will add supporting references as soon as I find them.