# What is the normal flora in Respiratory Tract (Upper and Lower)?

Tags: bacteriology

I opened my notes and it stated :

- pharynx, trachea, bronchi : << flora normal
- bronchioli & alveoli : steril

which I doubt because many papers I read stated that the lower-respiratory tract is not as sterile as we thought. However, the normal flora in the respiratory tract in all of these papers have different kind of bacteria. For example: one paper stated that the upper respiratory tract has *Corynebacterium* spp., *Dolosigranulum* spp., where other papers stated that viridans group streptococci, *Staphylococcus epidermidis*, etc. were found.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Can you please [edit] your question to add more detail including: 1) references & links to the papers you've consulted (example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609); and 2) the organism is question (I'm guessing you probably mean for humans, but this is [Biology.SE] not [MedicalSciences.SE]). As written this may not be a great fit for this site since it seems to be asking for a list of microorganism names, so please also tell us why you want to know this. That may influence what kind of answer is appropriate.

Comment: I've done some copy editing on your post, but please make sure I've not altered your intended meaning. In addition, note that the abbreviation of genus names (e.g. you originally wrote *S. epidermidis*) should only be done after the full name has been written out. In the future please check your posts for spelling and readability before posting. Finally, please clarify what your question is — are you asking whether the lower respiratory tract is normally sterile or are you interested in the composition of the normal flora — each post should only have a single question.