# Does biofilm formation hinder photosythesis?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, metabolism, photosynthesis, biofilms

In photosynthetic bacteria such as Cyanobacteria, Synechocystis sp. PCC 6803, the bacteria need access to both light, CO<sub>2</sub>, and water to perform photosynthesis.

However, in thick biofilm structures (e.g. a sphere or any 3D shape), I feel that physiologically the cells inside the biofilm 3D structure won't have direct access to sunlight, due to the outer cells forming layers blocking sunlight. Moreover, the inner cells are less likely to have the same access to carbon dioxide and water as the outer cells of the 3D construct.

So, Does the biofilm formation affect the viability and efficiency of the photosynthetic bacteria? or Do the bacteria have a mechanism to transfer the photons of light, gas, and moisture inside the biofilm?

Comment: Interesting question, In addition I wonder if the Cyanobacteria in a biofilm perform any activity normally seen in eukaryotic organisms. Namely nutrient transfer

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the constituents of Phototrophic biofilms are transparent by which light can easily pass. Phototrophic biofilm are very essential for the growth of photosynthetic microbs (colonies).Due to the presence of glycolipids the 3D structure act as lens which evenly distribute the light in the Phototrophic biofilm.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This looks like it could become a good answer, but answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if they include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion and thus inappropriate for this site. This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609). Please also check spelling and formatting before posting. ——— Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [answer] and [ask] effectively on this site.

Comment: Even if lights pass, does the wavelength delivered get affected. Furthermore, How about the nutrient and gases transfer?