# Why do some people accumulate more diglycerides in their muscle cells?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, lipids, diabetes-mellitus, insulin

The scientist Gerald Shulman has experimentally found that young lean adults in their early twenties that are children to people with type 2 diabetes often show muscle insulin resistance. He found that diglycerides within the muscle cells made it harder for the insulin activated "glucose transporter 4" to attach to the cell membrane.This causes these people to have raised insulin levels in order to get enough receptors to get glucose into the cells.

Also he has found that young adults of the same age and BMI that are not "sedentary" but more physically active do not have insulin resistance in the muscles.

Shulman believes that muscle insulin resistance due to diglycerides in muscle cells is what is starting a series of events that eventually can result in insulin resistance of the liver and diabetes. He has more then 450 published papers on related subjects and I can not really find "the one paper" where he claims to experimentally have verified his assertions.

This link is from a presentation from when he won the Banting Medal:

https://professional.diabetes.org/webcast/banting-medal-scientific-achievement%E2%80%94mechanisms-insulin-resistance%E2%80%94implications-obesity

There seems to be different theories as to why some people tend to accumulate more diglycerides in their muscle cells.

**Question**: What are the major reasons some people tend to accumulate more diglycerides in their muscle cells than others?

Comment: Remember the one question per post rule we have here? Asking so many in one post is liable to result in less than full coverage of the topic.

Comment: Further to @ARogueAnt., Asking so many questions is likely to have your question closed.  This is Q&A site, not a journal club or a discussion site. It might be worth your while looking at the Help on Asking Questions.

Comment: Thank you for focusing down to a single question, but I think you would get a better response if you supplemented the youtube links with references that supported the assertions you make. That would also demonstrate that you had done the expected research. ——— This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609). Also note that [tags](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) should be created sparingly, should never be redundant, and are most useful when they apply to multiple questions.

Comment: Having already made a criticism of your question I am reluctant to make another, but please accept it as having constructive intent. Professional scientists have an aversion to individual scientists publicising their views on videos. That is not how science is done. Like @tyresome, I read peer-reviewed papers and look at the evidence, not the person. A search for "diglycerides and insulin resistance" brought up a number of papers on this topic, implying that the correlation is well known. I suggest you read these yourself to see if there is any work on the cause of increased DGs.

Comment: @david I can see that this is a very active field of research, some clinical trials of diabetes-oriented medicine regulating lipid metabolism seem to be coming up. Some researcher thinks that fructose consumption via some pathways destroys lipid metabolism and thus causes insulin resistance. I am trying to lift the knowledge in this area (which do not seem to be widely spread) to a wider audience. For that I need answers from people with higher ranking than me on this site.

Comment: Clinical trials don't give information about mechanism. Neither do researchers' thoughts. If diglyceride synthesis increases as a response to some change, the mechanism by which this occurs can only be elucidated at the cellular and subcellular level. There are not too many biochemist frequent this site, and this is a rather specialized area. Sometimes I would try to research the literature out of interest, but I'm not inclined to do so as I'm busy and suspect that it may be a wild goose chase. You might try on SE Medical Sciences if you get nothing here, despite your bounty.