# Can features of modified plasmids be divided into prokaryotic features and eukaryotic features?

Tags: genetics, microbiology, plasmids

Here's what I understand and please correct me if I am wrong:

Plasmids modified for gene therapy or genetic engineering should contain factors for certain functions in prokaryotic cells. For example, it should contain an **origin of replication** for amplification in **prokaryotic cell** as **bacteria**.

In the same time, if it's being made to alter a mammalian cell, which is an **eukaryotic cell**, it should contain features that helps in **expression** of a certain gene as **Kozak sequence**

So is it right to say that we can divide features in the architecture of plasmids into features that serve prokaryotic functions and others that serve eukaryotic functions?

are these functions restricted to replication in prokaryotics and expression of genes in eukaryotics?

Comment: Plasmids are prokaryotic. If used as vectors for cloning they are still prokaryotic as regards their replication transcription and translation. The inserts in the vectors have the characteristics of the organism from which they originated. If the purpose is to introduce the insert into a eukaryote and hope to have it expressed then it will obviously require the transcriptional and translational signals to allow this occur, and these differ from prokaryotes to eukaryotes. You seem to understand this, so I don't quite see what your question is.

Comment: Not to be nitpicking, but while I agree that for cloning purposes plasmids are to be considered prokaryotic, eukaryotic plasmids do exist. The yeast 2-micron plasmid is one example ([PMC213983](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC213983/)).

Comment: @david i want to know if my reading is correct and also i want more specificty:
are these functions restricted to replication in prokaryotics and expression of genes in eukaryotics?

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t think you have a specific biological question in the terms of this list.

Answer (score -1):

are these functions restricted to replication in prokaryotics and expression of genes in eukaryotics?

Probably. We still use bacteria to make large quantities of plasmids, so we need to keep the essential prokaryote parts such as origin of replication. Also, we need selection markers markers such as antibiotic resistant gene fro pro and sometimes eukaryotes.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This looks like it could become a good answer, but answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if they include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion and thus inappropriate for this site. This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609). In addition, it is best to leave poor questions unanswered. ——— Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [answer] and [ask] effectively on this site.